# recaptcha doesn't show up in phantomjs if there is no iframe element with specific content

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, recaptcha

I'm trying to scrape a page with recaptcha widget using phantomjs but when I get the page it has no captcha image.

If I add an iframe element to the page, the image shows. The weirdest thing is that the image only appears if you make an iframe with specific content.

Here is the html code that I used to test (it's the normal code from recaptcha docs with the iframe element)

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfUUtMSAAAAAOBuPTWtMAnAu3l9AS-iHZb6iFpp&amp;error=">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfUUtMSAAAAAOBuPTWtMAnAu3l9AS-iHZb6iFpp&amp;error=" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <br>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
</form>
<iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
```

The iframe refers to the page frame.html and here is the "specific code" of it

```
<a><img src='http://c'></a>
```

If you tried to change the content of the frame.html a little bit you'll probably not get the captcha image.

The PhantomJS script that I used is this:

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/php_api/recaptcha.html';
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById("recaptcha_challenge_image").src;
        });
        console.log(p);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This is the first time I use PhantomJS so is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I don't think that you understood my issue 
the captcha is in the main page not in the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the additional iframe that you have on your page. The recaptcha script isn't loaded when the `page.open` callback is called. It hasn't created the reCaptcha table and hasn't loaded the captcha image. This is a timing issue.

You can wait a static amount of time with `setTimeout` or use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait until the image is present.

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var p = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.getElementById("recaptcha_challenge_image").src;
            });
            console.log(p);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Don't forget that `phantom.exit` should also be called after the timeout otherwise you just exit prematurely.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem i just have two more questions:
you said that the captcha script isn't loaded because of the page.open callback.....is this some sort of spam security that google have ?
And why when i put the iframe without setting a timeout i can see the captcha ?

Comment: It's not really defined in the docs *when* the `page.open` callback is called. I would say that the reCaptcha code is dubious, because it uses `document.write`, but I doubt it is done for spam security. Regarding the second question ... it is possible that the additional iframe loading produces enough time for the engine to load the captcha table, but somehow I doubt this. I can't deny what you saw.

Comment: That's a great diagnosis, but if you're in doubt you can use the codes that i put and test that your self. Thanks alot